# How to programmatically create a Google Sheet with the ability to run UrlFetchApp from an Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I've been digging around and not finding a solution to this.

It appears the only way to use UrlFetchApp is to use an installable trigger. However, installable triggers cannot be added by the Google Sheets or Drive REST api. The triggers must be enabled by hand and authorized manually. They also do not copy when a document is copied in drive.

These limitations seem to be by design, unless I'm missing something. But it makes it impossible to make an on-demand google sheet that can communicate with an external server, even if I own the document. Any ideas for a solution that can scale?

Comment: Why is the use of urfFetch contingent upon triggers?  I think some addition information might be helpful

Comment: @Cooper because UrlFetchApp is a service that requires authorization, and only installable triggers can be used with services that require authz

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine `How to programmatically create a Google Sheet with the ability to run UrlFetchApp from an Apps Script?`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: I understand that but why you do require triggers?

Comment: @Cooper oh sorry I misunderstood. I am sending the contents of the changed spreadsheet row to sync with an external database. I want to use the onEdit trigger for that.

Comment: @Tanaike I am creating a spreadsheet for each customer. When a customer edits the spreadsheet, I want it to sync with my database, without polling the spreadsheet.